# How to query for grouped distinct records that both have null and non-null values in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

I am trying to create a query that returns a result set with a distinct (car) column based on another (data) column that is non-null.

In the example below, if there is a non-null value found in the data column then return the single instance with a value and if not, return the value with null and always maintain the distinctness of the first column.

```
let Car = datatable(car, data:string) 
[
    "mercedes", "fast",
    "mercedes", null,
    "tesla", null
    "toyota", "good",
    "sonata", null,
    "sonata", null,
    "sonata", "amazing" 
];
```

So the desired output would be:

```
"mercedes", "fast",
"tesla", null,
"toyota", "good",
"sonata", "amazing",
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option would be using a combination of `set_difference()` and `make_set()`:

- `make_set()` will create a set of all unique values of `data` (by `car`, the aggregation key)
- `dynamic([""])` is an array with an empty string
- `set_difference()` will produce the difference between the two former arrays - to provide a set with a non-empty string (or an empty set)
- last, by accessing the first element of the result set (using `[0]`), you'll get the first element that's not-empty (or null, if the set is empty)

```
datatable(car:string, data:string) 
[
    "mercedes", "",
    "mercedes", "fast",
    "tesla", "",
    "toyota", "good",
    "sonata", "",
    "sonata", "",
    "sonata", "amazing" 
]
| summarize data = set_difference(make_set(data), dynamic([""]))[0] by car
```

| car | data |
| --- | --- |
| mercedes | fast |
| tesla |  |
| toyota | good |
| sonata | amazing |

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with the functions?

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: Thanks for your help!